# Why does $0=/bin/foo when /bin is a symlink

Tags: linux, bash, path, symbolic-link

I installed my bash scripts into `/usr/bin/app.sh` and `/usr/bin/lib.sh`

`app.sh` includes

```
source "/usr/bin/lib.sh"
```

and `lib.sh` includes

```
if [ "/usr/bin/app.sh" == "$0"] ...
```

When I run `app.sh` from the shell, this test fails because `$0` is actually `/bin/app.sh`. On the filesystem, `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`

What's the best way for `lib.sh` to determine whether it's being included by `app.sh` (as opposed to `other-app.sh`) in such a way that it won't get tricked by the environment? I would have thought absolute paths without symlinks would have done the job, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether two files are the same, you need to check the index (inode) number, which is displayed with:

```
stat -L -c %i FilePath
```

So your check now becomes:

```
if [ $(stat -L -c %i "/usr/bin/app.sh") == $(stat -L -c %i "$0") ] ...
```

This works regardless of any links in the directory path, or even a symbolic or hard link to the file itself.

To be strictly accurate (thanks to @ilkkachu for pointing this out), there is a very unlikely chance that two different files with the same name could have the same inode on two different file systems. To avoid this, include the device number in the comparison:

```
if [ $(stat -L -c %d:%i "/usr/bin/app.sh") == $(stat -L -c %d:%i "$0") ] ...
```

Comment: In principle, comparing inode numbers is only valid within the same filesystem. Though you may not be likely to hit on a collision by chance.

Comment: @ilkkachu - Good point, which I overlooked. I've elaborated my answer to take account of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`readlink -f /path/to/whatever` will tell you the canonical path (which will be `/usr/bin/app.sh` in your example).

From [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink):

> canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively; all but the last component must exist